# How can I get the Register form on the front page?

Tags: forms, theming, hooks, 8

I've managed to create a new theme, customize the front page pretty much how I wanted it, and I've encountered a problem.

I need to get the register form (create new account) in a pop-up on the front page.

After following the instructions from [Form API in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2117411):

```
    <?php

/**
* @file
* Functions to support theming in the themename theme.
*/

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\UrlHelper;

/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for HTML document templates.
*/

function themename_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\register');

return $form;
}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, because I get an error saying that is not a valid form. I have also tried using the form id as a parameter, still no valid form.

Could anyone please help? I could use a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form id shoud be `Drupal\user\RegisterForm`. However, because the register form is attached to an entity, you can't use `getForm` directly. You need to create an entity and then get the register form for that entity.

The role of the preprocess function is to add / modify / delete template variables via the `$variables` parameter, so you need to add the form to that array rather than return it.

Something like this should work:

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {  
  $entity = \Drupal::entityManager()
    ->getStorage('user')
    ->create(array());

  $formObject = \Drupal::entityManager()
    ->getFormObject('user', 'register')
    ->setEntity($entity);

  $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formObject);
  $variables['register_form'] = $form;
}
```

Now you should be able to print the form via `{{ login_form }}` in the `page.html.twig` template.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use the module FormBlock (https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) to make the registration form available as a block, and then add a "popup" region to your theme, and using the blocks UI place the block in that region just for the front page.

Answer (score 0):

This is working well for me at the moment:

```
$formBuilder = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder');
$form = $formBuilder->getForm(User::create(array()), 'register', array());
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter answer, mixing the previous one would be to use the entity.form_builder service for the register form. The answer of @joekers is good on that, it's not necessary to load the entityManager just to display a form.

```
// Load the service renderer
$render = Drupal::service('renderer');

// User login form
$login_form = Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm');
$variables['login_form'] = $render->renderPlain($login_form);

// User registration form
$register_form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm(\Drupal\user\Entity\User::create([]), 'register', []);
$variables['register_form'] = $render->renderPlain($register_form);
```

As we can see, the method to render Register and Login forms are different, because Register is link to the User entity.